# Help on key.json file

Tags: truffle-compile

Dears,

I am getting the below error while trying to compile the contract.

```
~/Desktop/TstToken$ truffle compile
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kdf' of undefined
    at Function.Wallet.fromV3 (/home/fkp/Desktop/TstToken/node_modules/ethereumjs-wallet/index.js:237:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/fkp/Desktop/TstToken/truffle.js:5:43)
    at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Function.Config.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-config/index.js:259:1)
```

I am using the key file from Ethereumjs-wallet.

It will be great if there is a workaround for the same.

Comment: I am just wondering why you would require a keystore file for compiling contracts. Can you post your truffle.js please.

Comment: Can you pls put it formatted into your post above. It‘s difficult to read from the comment. Moreover, it‘s important to know what‘s on line 5, since it‘s causing the exception.